# 3D Triangulation similar to Hawkeye

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d, triangulation, stereo-3d

Forgive me if this question has been asked before, but I'd like to know where to start to achieve stereo vision to convert 2D coordinates into 3D coordinates.  I'm trying to track balls like Hawkeye in 3D.  I have two high speed cameras and I'm able to detect the ball in each camera.  I understand that I need to calibrate the cameras, synchronize them and run some algorithm to remove lens distortion etc.  However, I don't know what the next step is to convert the 2D coordinates to world 3D coordinates.

Does anybody know how to perform triangulation who can assist me with this?  Also the cameras will not be parallel to each other, but at different angles, so somehow, I need to know the location of each camera in terms of their 3D coordinates.

Any help with this would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: take a look at a small intro here: http://multimedia.ceti.gr/index.php/3d-laser-scanning-explained/ it refers primarily to laser scanning but the concept of triangulation is the same... you might also need to check stereo vision resources as you are using two cameras

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Are you looking for the theory behind the triangulation process, or do you want to apply this in OpenCV?

Comment: I want to know in practical terms (using either OpenCV or any other code or library), not just in theory, how I can triangulate to find the 3D location of a ball using a simple two camera setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert 2D into 3D for two calibrated cameras you would use these formulas:
z = focal*baseline/disparity
x = z*u/focal
y = z*v/focal

where
focal - the focal length of you camera in pixels
u = column-Cx, Cx~image_width/2 but calibration will give you more precise value
v = -row+Cy, Cy~image_height/2
Baseline - horizontal distance between cameras
disparity - difference in horizontal position of the ball in two images

Strictly speaking you need to do rectification only for working with dense stereo. For sparse stereo you only need calibration.

Comment: That's great, thank you.  A little context, I'm trying to produce a system that can detect a soccer ball going over the line.  If I take the two cameras and focus them on the goals, do they have to be parallel or can they be any angle/distance between each other?  Also, how do I accurately find out the position of the cameras required for the triangulation process?

Comment: you don’t need to have parallel cameras but then you might be solving a bit more involved system of equations. Camera separation should be large enough compared to the distance so, for example, if cameras are parallel and d=f*B/z you have to ensure you have several pixels of disparity at the distance your goal is located. As for camera calibration - you will need an intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of your cameras to solve triangulation problem. This means solving pinhole camera equations for a 3D point (3 unknowns) while you have 4 equations (2 cameras x 2d coordinates in your image).

Comment: as a post above said you can combine intrinsic and extrinsic parameters in projection matrix and use  triangulatePoints() to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found [fragment of 'Learning OpenCV' book](http://books.google.pl/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&lpg=PP1&hl=pl&pg=PA415#v=onepage&q&f=false). It seems to be a good source of knowledge about either theory behind and implementation in opencv. Although, the API in book is outdated, the general mechanism still is up-to-date. To sum up, they recommend:

1. Remove distortion (you can do this already if you have calibrated cameras)
2. Adjust distances and angles between cameras
3. Find the same features on both images
4. Estimate depth by simple calculation considering object's position on an image.

Comment: The book Learning OpenCV is leading to the answer of @Vlad. You can find the full book here: [link](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/vision/dipakmj/papers/OReilly%20Learning%20OpenCV.pdf)